# Angular Material cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport Not Correctly Scrolling on Content Update

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` to render a list of messages in a chat room. The messages are stored in an array of strings and the array is updated every time a message is received.

My issue is that when using `scrollTo({ bottom: 0 })` on the viewport immediately after updating the content it only scrolls to the second last item in the viewport.

If the `scrollTo()` function is placed within a `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` then the viewport will correctly scroll to the bottom. However, the problem with this is there is a slight delay between the content update on the page and the scroll. This causes the viewport and scrollbar to erratically jump to the bottom on every new message, which is quite visually jarring.

Is there a way to delay the page update until the viewport has been re-rendered and correctly scrolled to the bottom?

The viewport:

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="50" id="messages" #messageViewport>
  <mat-card *cdkVirtualFor="let message of messages">
    <mat-card-content>
      {{ message }}
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

The relevant component code:

```js
messages: string[] = [];
@ViewChild('messageViewport') messageViewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

ngOnInit() {
  this.chatService.connect().subscribe((messages) => {
    this.messages = messages;
    this.messageViewport.scrollTo({ bottom: 0 });
  });
}
```